# Antd table expand row and place textarea inside

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am trying to implement row editing with Antd where when I click on the Edit link the row expands and has a textarea inside the user can type into. I haven't been able to figure out how to trigger row expansion (didn't see any onclick event handlers on the + sign) nor how to get access to the expanded row element to slide a form field in there in a non hacky way.

This is the current code - https://gist.github.com/llevar/8f9a68bcc15ab0e37defb14a5126c5ad. The goal is to have the column "Configuration" with JSON in it end up in a text area upon clicking Edit.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try 
`onExpandedRowsChange` props and `onExpand` they give you access to the expanded row callback and expanded row change.

edit:
I haven't try this, but I think you should be able to programatically expand rows with `expandedRowKeys` and state. and use the `expandedRowRender` to conditionally render "view mode" and "edit mode(text area)", also you can add a save button to save the textarea values and turn it back to "view mode"

`onExpand` is trigger when you press the + icon (or expand the row via rowClick)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is helpful but I'm not sure I've got a full understanding of what you mean (newly back to JS world after a good 10 year hiatus). I am assuming that you are suggesting that using the onExpand() event I will get a reference to the row to put a form field in there, and using onExpandedRowsChange() I can save user's input. Is this right? I'm still not clear about how I can trigger the expand using an Edit link. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I added some information, I'm not sure if I understood 100% what you want to achieve.

Comment: Well, I've dug into it a bit more and it doesn't quite work. Pushing a row index into `expandedRowKeys` does expand the row, but it does not update the row icon [+] to a [-]. The only way I've seen it work was by using built in methods like `expandRowByClick` and `expandAll`. `onExpand` doesn't cause an expand but is the event fired when an expand happens. Pushing a row index into `expandedRowKeys` does not fire `onExpand`. So far I cant't to get it to work. Also, how do you recommend implementing the edit and view modes? This should be a Row state I think, but how do I get access to the row?

Comment: To clarify, I was able to get this to work finally. The issue is that expandedRowKeys uses rowKeys (duh) not row indexes. I was thrown off track by the usage of row indexes in the Antd examples, but it turns out their examples don't really work with indexes either.